# How to call method in ViewController from viewmodel in swift 5?

Tags: ios, swift, mvvm

I am using MVVM design pattern in iOS project. I am trying to call method in viewcontroller from viewmodel.

```
import Foundation

class NotificationViewModel {

    var onCompletion: ((_ success: Bool) -> ())?

    func saveNotification(notification: Dictionary<String, Any>) {
        print("notification save")
        //other logic
        onCompletion?(true)
    }
   }
```

"saveNotification" method getting called from appdelegate when notification received

```
func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter,
                                didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse,
                                withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {
        let userInfo = response.notification.request.content.userInfo

        guard
            let aps = userInfo[AnyHashable("aps")] as? NSDictionary,
            let alert = aps["alert"] as? NSMutableDictionary
            else {
                // handle any error here
                return
            }   

        NotificationViewModel().saveNotification(notification: alert as! Dictionary<String, Any>)
        }
```

trying to call method in viewcontroller when "saveNotification" trigger

```
     class AlertViewController: BaseViewController{


            var viewModel = NotificationViewModel()

            override func viewDidLoad() {
                super.viewDidLoad()

                self.viewModel.onCompletion = { success in
                    // this should be executed when `saveNotification()` will be called
// **** this is never getting called ******
                    print("calling from viewmodel")
                    methodToCall()
                }
            }

          func methodToCall(){
            //logic
          }
      }
```

But the method in viewdidload is not getting called anytime.

Please suggest if its possible or any other way to achieve this?
Thanks for help

Answer (score 0):

It's because you are calling the `saveNotification` method on a new instance of `NotificationViewModel` whose `onCompletion` is not set, and hence would not call the `methodToCall` method in the `AlertViewController`.

Comment: Thanks for help and clarifying. Is there any way so that i can achieve result?

Comment: The question here was why it doesn't work, technically my job here is done. But, just because you asked you might wanna do some research on Notification and Observers to achieve what you might be looking for.

Comment: sure... Thanks for guiding